Athena query with IN operator not returning results
I deployed a CloudWatch metrics connector in my AWS account to pull CloudWatch metrics using Amazon Athena.
I am running a query with IN operator like below:
SELECT * from metric_samples where metric_name IN ('A','B') -- this returns no results

However, when I individually fetch the record which match metric_name = 'A' or metric_name = 'B' using the below, it works and pulls the data:
SELECT * from metric_samples where metric_name IN ('A') -- this returns results
SELECT * from metric_samples where metric_name IN ('B') -- this returns results

Has anyone faced a similar issue?
I am expecting results to be returned when multiple values are specified in the IN clause.
